# Persisting Scope beyond get request in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-http

I have the following code:

```
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/getStuff'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.stuffData= response.data.length;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
    });

console.log("amount is:" +$scope.stuffData);


});
```

In this instance, my log gives:

```
amount is:undefined
```

Some other SO questions suggest running $scope.$apply to make my scope persist. To this I get the following error:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

What is the correct way to persist my scope? I.E what is the correct way to assign values of a get request to a scope variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP calls are **asynchronous**. Your `console.log` is probably called **before** your app retrieved the data. When `console.log` is called, `$scope.stuffData` is not yet defined.

Move your `console.log` to the `.then`.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/getStuff'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.stuffData = response.data.length;
      console.log("amount is:", $scope.stuffData); // <-- It should work
}, function errorCallback(response) {
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I want the result to persist outside of the request.

Comment: **It does**. Since you store it in `$scope`, try to show it in HTML. Eg: `<div>{{stuffData}}</div>`.

Comment: @MattBoyle Could you please check again if is solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**The HTTP Requests run Asynchronously.** In order to handle this concept you have to use [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Angular uses callback functions for handling asynchronous HTTP calls.

In your case `$scope.stuffData` is undefined because the `console.log` runs before http request gets data in `.then()` callback function.

This would be solved if you've added the `console.log` in `.then()` function.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I want the result to persist outside of the request. I guess once the promise is returned I want that value assigned to the scope?

Comment: Excatly. You need to asign the data from response on your scope. But even this is not enough. Your `console.log` runs **before** the callback function runs.That is why your `$scope.stuffData` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The console.log() is executed before the data is retrieved (http call is asynchronous), so the value is undefined yet. Try checking the value inside the function, after success:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/getStuff'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.stuffData= response.data.length;
       console.log("amount is:" +$scope.stuffData);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
       console.log("Response error"); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try with this one please--

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/getStuff'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(response); 
      $scope.stuffData= obj.data.length;
      $scope.$apply();
      console.log($scope.stuffData);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
    });




});
```